# How to save non-top level JSON elements in table columns using spring xd jdbc sink?

Tags: jdbc, multiple-columns, spring-xd, sink

I have the following data structure

```
{
 metadata: {
     eventId:string
     eventName: string
     ts: date time string
    . . .
},
 data:{
   // complex event payload
 }
}
```

I am getting these events from a message bus and need to write the message into a relational table with the following columns

eventId | eventName | ts(Date object) | payload (clob)

How do I achieve these goals in Spring XD?

1. save non-toplevel elements into multiple columns
2. convert the metadata.ts into DBMS's date object

I was thinking something like this.

jms|jdbc --columns=payload.metadata.eventId,payload.metadata.eventName,someMagicFunction(payload.metadata.ts),payload

But, it was throwing some errors in HSQLDB.

```
2016-09-28T07:06:41-0700 WARN JMS Session Delivery Thread - $TMPAPPID$112880967$$SESSION$0:4720332838885165348 listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcMessageHandler#0]; nested ex
ception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [insert into ces_test5 (payload.metadata.eventId, payload
.metadata.eventName, payload
.metadata.ts,  payload) values(?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: too many identifier parts: PAYLOAD
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:139) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE
.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEA
SE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:n
a]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEA
SE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELE
ASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEA
```

Is #1 (saving non-toplevel elements into multiple columns) even possible?

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you don't explicitly specify payload when referring the column names here:

`jms|jdbc --columns=metadata.eventId,metadata.eventName,someMagicFunction(metadata.ts),payload`

The JDBC sink operates on `payload` data so you don't have to specify it.